# Roots of smoothing operators

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, integral-operators

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a smooth, compact Riemann manifold and $K:M\times M\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth, symmetric nonnegative function. We regard is as the Schwartz kernel of a smoothing operator. In particular, it  defines a compact,  integral operator
$$
A_K: L^2(M,dV_g)\to L^2(M,dV_g),\;\; (A_Kf)(x)=\int_M K(x,y)f(y)~ dV_g(y).
$$
Assume that $A_K$ is  *positive  semidefinite*, i.e., $K$ is a Mercer kernel. As such it  has functional roots $A_K^{1/n}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

I have two  questions.

1. Is it true  that these functional roots are also  smoothing operators?
2. Is there anything known about  the decay to $0$ of the positive eigenvalues of $A_K$?

As an example to have in mind is the heat kernel $K=H_t$ of the Laplacian so $A_K= e^{-t\Delta}$, $t>0$ fixed.

More generally, Mercer kernels as above are covariance  kernels  of random smooth functions on $M$.

Here is a special case  that is  relevant in manifold learning.

Suppose that $M$ is a compact smooth submanifold of a finite dimensional Euclidean space $V$. Denote by $\Vert-\Vert$ the Euclidean norm on $V$.  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ Define
$$K : M\times M\to \bR,\;]\;; K(x,y) = e^{-\Vert x-y\Vert^2/2}. $$

An old theorem of Schoenberg shows that $A_K$ is positive definite. It is obviously smoothing. Is it true that $A_K^{1/2}$ is also smoothing?

Thank you.

Comment: @Derek: I suspect Liviu meant what he wrote for question 2, that is anything known about the decay rate of the _original_ operator.

Comment: For the decay problem, I think this [previous MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/377416/3948) is pointing in the right direction. The notations in that paper is hard to parse, but I *think* (after a few minutes puzzling after it) the main theorem, in your case where $K\in C^\infty$ and $M$ is compact, tells you that the eigenvalues should decay to zero faster than any polynomial.

Comment: The hypothesis that .$K$ is nonnegative does not imply that $A_K$ is positive: look at the case of zero-dimensional $M$.

Comment: @JohannesEbert You are absolutely correct.   Thanks for picking this up. I want $A_K$ to be  positive.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thanks for pointing me to that answer. There is a usefu suggestion  in one of the comments there